# addEventHandler for every object VS loop through objects in event

Tags: javascript, dom-events

This is a simple question I'd just like some insight into:

I have 1000 JavaScript objects.

Situation 1: Each of these objects adds an event listener to a button, so the browser runs through all of those functions and calls the handling script.

Situation 2: Some object adds an event listener to the button, and reacts to it by looping through all of the objects and calling the handling script on each.

I simply can't deduce which is faster and I also know there may be more ways than this, so, insights?

Comment: Investigate the topic of **event bubbling.**

Comment: @Pointy Event bubbling wouldn't help here.  He's just asking about the difference between attaching multiple events to a single button vs. one event that does a lot of stuff.

Comment: Ah I see. Well I saw "1000" and it didn't occur to me that there'd be 1000 different things to do for **one** button click.

Comment: can we see a simplified example of what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the difference would be negligible, if you are really curious you can run each scenario through [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/) to find out.

I don't see any reason in this case not to take the more maintainable solution, and having one event handler attached to the button that loops internally will be a lot easier to debug in the future.

Comment: I too thought it would be easier to dev and debug... But then I realised that it's very inflexible. Getting it to work for each of the 1000 objects requires proxying the event to each object.. Which meant 1000 DIFFERENT functions, but it was looped natively, saving speed... Then looping in JavaScript, let me call the object's methods much simpler without any proxying and all from the same prototype.... It's very anti-intuitive, the way event handling works, it needs a context argument to be of any real use.

Comment: Interesting, the more I think about it I don't think either situation would be fun to debug.  One thing I hadn't thought about is that for each event the browser has to create an event object to pass to attached handlers.  Over the course of 1000 events there's probably some cost for that in terms of speed and memory use.  Using one event handler wouldn't have that added overhead.